# Reverse engineering

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, file-format, decoding

I have a binary-only copy of an application written in Delphi 7; as part of its execution, it writes some data into a text file (not in plain text).

Is it possible to extract the data from the file if I know part of the input data and have a copy of this file?  (What if it's encrypted?)  I have no idea about the structure of the mentioned file.

And no, I don't have source code for the application -- I think that's obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you would have to reverse engineer this application first (IDA, HIEW) and/or debug it while it stores the data to the file, contact me if you need more help.